# Error: Could not load database driver type mysqli!

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

При переносе магазина на OpenCart версии 3.0.2.0 на новый хостинг получил следующую ошибку:

> Error: Could not load database driver type mysqli!

А в логах такой вот ERROR:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant DIR_DATABASE - assumed 'DIR_DATABASE' in /var/www/*******/data/www/*******/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_db.php on line 6

Сам `vq2-system_library_db.php` выглядит так:

```html
<?php
class DB {
 private $driver;

 public function __construct($driver, $hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
  $file = DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php';

  if (file_exists($file)) {
   require_once(VQMod::modCheck($file));

   $class = 'DB' . $driver;

   $this->driver = new $class($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
  } else {
   exit('Error: Could not load database driver type ' . $driver . '!');
  }
 }

 public function query($sql) {
  return $this->driver->query($sql);
 }

 public function escape($value) {
  return $this->driver->escape($value);
 }

 public function countAffected() {
  return $this->driver->countAffected();
 }

 public function getLastId() {
  return $this->driver->getLastId();
 }
}
?>
```

То есть злится на `$file = DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php';`

*звёздочками убрал имя пользователя и сайта соответственно*

Answer (score 0):

Ну вроде все очевидно:

```
$file = DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php';
```

Этого пути не существует, собсна надо открывать конфиг и смотреть на:

```
define('DIR_DATABASE', '../system/database/');
```

И прописать правильный путь до вашего файла

Comment: После того, как вписал базу данных (путь пришлось несколько иначе вписывать) слетела вёрстка сайта и теперь элементы все смешаны